# Java / JSP Send TCP packet and wait for response

Tags: java, jsp, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to send a TCP packet. It sends correctly to the server but sender is not getting response (server is sending response back correctly). Client doesn't even process code afeter sending the packet...

```
 Socket socket = new Socket (ip, port);

 PrintWriter mOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);  
 mOut.print("DSPSYSSTS");

 //Everything works fine until here

 BufferedReader mIn = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream ()));
 String fromClient = mIn.readLine();
 out.println ("Client Message: " + fromClient);

 mOut.close();
 mIn.close ();      
 socket.close ();
```

The JSP doesn't print the input and it remains loading forever. What's wrong?

Returning String of `systemRequest.request` in below code

```
ReadSpoolFile readSplf = new ReadSpoolFile(splfArray.get(0));
String splfContent = readSplf.read();

GetSystemStatus getSysSts = new GetSystemStatus();
String systemStatus = getSysSts.get(splfContent);
return systemStatus + "\r\n";
```

Server side Response:

```
String response = systemRequests.request(message, SystemRequests.SILENT_OFF);

ChannelBuffer mCbResponse;

if(response != null){
mCbResponse = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(response.getBytes());
mChannel.write(mCbResponse);    //<------Write response
```

Comment: Can you post the serverside code? My suspicion is that the server is not sending a `\r\n`, therefor the `.readLine()` method will hang because it has not received a new line character.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I also tried removing `\r\n` and it produces the same error but I't wasn't my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mOut.print("DSPSYSSTS");
mOut.flush();
...
```